# Is there a way to have zsh completion to be based entirely on the prefix of the word and not the suffix?

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

In zsh, if I write:

```
git --ver<tab>
```

it will complete to:

```
git --version
```

but if I try to complete:

```
git --ver<tab>asdf
```

it won't complete because it see's the rest of the word doesn't match any of the possible completions. Is there a way to have it only consider the prefix when completing and ignore the suffix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is: Set the [`COMPLETE_IN_WORD` shell option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-COMPLETEINWORD) and add the [`_prefix` completer](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fprefix):

```sh
autoload -Uz compinit; compinit
setopt completeinword
zstyle ':completion:*' completer \
  _oldlist _expand _complete _correct _history _ignored _prefix
```

`_prefix` will try all completers that have come before it, but without including the text to the right of the cursor.